# How to build a Redux + ReduxToolkit store with a repeating nested slice?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, state-management

Let's say my state looks something like this (taken from https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape):

```
{
    posts : {
        byId : {
            "post1" : {
                id : "post1",
                author : "user1",
                body : "......",
                comments : ["comment1", "comment2"]
            },
            "post2" : {
                id : "post2",
                author : "user2",
                body : "......",
                comments : ["comment3", "comment4", "comment5"]
            }
        },
        allIds : ["post1", "post2"]
    },
    comments : {
        byId : {
            "comment1" : {
                id : "comment1",
                author : "user1",
                comment : ".....",
            },
            "comment2" : {
                id : "comment2",
                author : "user2",
                comment : ".....",
            }
        },
        allIds : ["comment1", "comment2"]
    },
    users : {
        byId : {
            "user1" : {
                username : "user1",
                name : "User 1",
            },
            "user2" : {
                username : "user2",
                name : "User 2",
            }
        },
        allIds : ["user1", "user2"]
    }
}
```

And accordingly I've created 3 slices using Redux-Toolkit's `createSlice`: postsSlice, commentsSlice, usersSlice.
This is simple enough.

But now I want to add another layer to the state to keep track of blogs, and so the whole structure above needs to be nested and repeated for each blog:

```
{
    blogs: {
        byId: {
            "blog1": {
                posts: {...},
                comments: {...},
                users: {...}
            },
            "blog2": {
                posts: {...},
                comments: {...},
                users: {...}
            },
        },
        allIds: ["blog1", "blog2"]
    }
}
```

Now I need to use `createSlice` to create a new slice, blogsSlice. But for each blog item in this slice I need a sub-state that is comprised of the other 3 slices.

How do I combine the slices/reducers in a way that will actually create this structure? How should I define the initial state and reducer functions that I pass to `createSlice` in order to make this structure work?

Answer (score 1):

I actually put together a gist demonstrating something very similar to this, for a notional ChatRoom > ChatMessages structure.  This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but hopefully it will give you an idea of how you *can* structure things that will server as an inspiration.

Pasting the entire snippet here as an example:

```
// Example of using multiple / nested `createEntityAdapter` calls 
// within a single Redux Toolkit slice

interface Message {
  id: string;
  roomId: string;
  text: string;
  timestamp: string;
  username: string;
}

interface ChatRoomEntry {
  id: string;
  messages: EntityState<Message>;
}

const roomsAdapter = createEntityAdapter<ChatRoomEntry>();
const messagesAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Message>();

const fetchRooms = createAsyncThunk(
  "chats/fetchRooms",
  chatsAPI.fetchRooms
);

const fetchMessages = createAsyncThunk(
  "chats/fetchMessages",
  async (roomId) => {
    return chatsAPI.fetchMessages(roomId);
  }
)

const chatSlice = createSlice({
  name: "chats",
  initialState: roomsAdapter.getInitialState(),
  reducers: {
  
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addCase(fetchRooms.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      const roomEntries = action.payload.map(room => {
        return {id: room.id, messages: messagesAdapter.getInitialState()};
      });
      
      roomsAdapter.setAll(state, roomEntries);
    })
    .addCase(fetchMessages.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      const roomId = action.meta.arg;
      const roomEntry = state.entities[roomId];
      if (roomEntry) {
        messagesAdapter.setAll(roomEntry.messages, action.payload);
      }
    })
  }
})

/*
Resulting state:
{
  ids: ["chatRoom1"],
  entities: {
    chatRoom1: {
      id: "chatRoom1",
      messages: {
        ids: ["message1", "message2"],
        entities: {
          message1: {id: "message1", text: "hello"},
          message2: {id: "message2", text: "yo"},
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my example I used a normalized state for simplicity, but my actual state is not normalized and the concept of entities doesn't really apply, so using createEntityAdapter is not a solution for me and that's why I've created a slice instead for each "entity". In your solution, can I replace the use of adapters (such as messagesAdapter.setAll) with calling a reducer function from another slice? Is it allowed to call reducers from within other reducers? If so, must it be in extraReducers or can it be in the regular reducers?

Comment: A reducer can call any other functions it needs to do its work, as long as they all collectively follow the rules of reducers. A reducer can even truly mutate _new_ values inside of itself, as long as the final externally visible result is immutable. So sure, reducer A can call reducer B inside of itself to produce an intermediate value as part of the calculation process.